# Открытие блока при клике на любую кнопку

Tags: jquery

Суть проблемы в том что на странице имеется несколько кнопок в одинаковым id нужный мне блок открывается при нажатии только на первую кнопку, которая какбы выше по dom

Как мне сделать так чтобы блок открывался при нажатии на любой элемент у которого стоит id на открытие блока, независимо от их числа

открытие на jquery, сайт на joomla

Comment: на странице может только один одинаковый id, также покажите что Вы сделали?

Comment: так а чего показывать, когда getElementById возвращает строго один элемент?

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно привести разметку в соответствие стандартам html, тогда всё станет работать.

Answer (score 0):

Так и есть, я и забыл что id должен быть уникальным, поставил обоим классы и всё встало как надо!

Благодарю!